# Find all the elements which has no duplicate in multiple HashSet of Integers in Java

Tags: java, set

In multiple `HashSet` of `Integers` I want to get all those elements, which has no duplicate. i.e. which came only once in union of all the `HashSet`. I am not able to conceptualize it programmatically.

 As an example, consider set first contains {2,4,6,8,9}, second set contains {2,8,9} and third set contains {2,4,8,9}. In all these set, element 6 occurs only once.
How to find all the elements which has no duplicate in multiple HashSet of Integers in Java?

Comment: You have a set of sets, or is there a definite count of them?

Comment: so final answer that you want is 6... right?

Comment: @FahimParkar: yes, for the above example ans is 6.

Comment: @JanDvorak: i have multiple (definite count) set, which contains integer elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could hold the set of elements that occur at least once and at least twice. It's a bit of manual looping but it's possible. This will work for any number of sets to difference and will not modify the input:

```
public static Set<E> unique(Set<? extends E>... sets){
   Set<E> once = new HashSet<E>();
   Set<E> twice = new HashSet<E>();

   for(Set<? extends E> set:sets){
      for(E el:set){
         if(once.contains(el)){
            twice.add(el);
         } else {
            once.add(el);
         }
      }
   }

   once.removeAll(twice);
   return once;
}
```

Ideone: http://ideone.com/reGDBy

Example usage:

```
Set<Integer> set1, set2, set3;
...
Set<Integer> u = unique(set1, set2, set3);
```

Example of evaluation:

> As an example, consider set first contains {2,4,6,8,9}, second set contains {2,8,9} and third set contains {2,4,8,9}. In all these set, element 6 occurs only once.

- After the first inner loop completes, `once` contains {2,4,6,8,9} and `twice` is empty.
- Adding the second set: 2, 8 and 9 are already in the `once` set, so they are added to the `twice` set.
- `once` is now {2,4,6,8,9}, `twice` is now {2,8,9}.
- From the third set: 2 is re-added to `twice`, 4 is added to `twice`, 8, 9 are re-added to `twice`.
- `once` is now {2,4,6,8,9} (union of all sets), `twice` is now {2,4,8,9} (elements that occur at least twice).
- remove `twice` from `once`. `once` is now {6}. Return `once`.

Comment: can you have this example with three lists? OP has 3 sets... with 2 sets its easier...

Comment: @FahimParkar modified to use varargs and added an example.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I think you need to change `public Set<E> unique(Collection<Set<? extends E>> sets) {` to `public <E> Set<E> unique(Collection<Set<? extends E>> sets) {` . Also would be helpful if you can compile it [here](http://ideone.com)

Comment: @JanDvorak: There is a minor change in you modified post.`After the first inner loop completes, once contains {2,4,6,8,9} and twice is empty.`. Can you compile and share your code [here](http://ideone.com)

Comment: I will add a test case to ideone.

Comment: @JanDvorak: [Here](http://ideone.com/osTba6) `Main` method is empty. U cn call ur method to make it more clear. Anyways thank you.

Comment: @RaviJoshi updated with an example. Added `static` as well - no need for it to be an instance method.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Cool enough... I too had added `static` in my eclipse code as well. Thank you buddy.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Sure. I did it. you rock.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that using the `contains()` method. First, create a new HashSet from all the other sets. Then iterate over this set and check if other sets `contains()` the specified element. If two or more lists contain it, then you have a duplicate and can `continue`. If only one set contains the element, you can store it somewhere in a different result set for example.

I wrote a utility method to achieve what you need:

```
public static <E> HashSet<E> uniques(HashSet<E>... sets){
    HashSet<E> everything = new HashSet<E>();
    for(HashSet<E> set : sets){
        everything.addAll(set);
    }
    HashSet<E> uniques = new HashSet<E>();
    for(E e : everything){
        int count = 0;
        for(HashSet<E> set : sets){
            if(set.contains(e)){
                count++;
            }
            if(count > 1){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(count == 1){
            uniques.add(e);
        }

    }
    return uniques;
}
```

Comment: so, for each element in each set, if no other set contains it, return the element?

Comment: @JanDvorak or store it in a results set, doesn't really matter.

Comment: I'm afraid my approach is faster.

Answer (score 1):

A [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) version using intermediate [Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html):

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <E> Set<E> uniqueElements(Set<? extends E>... sets) {
    final Multiset<E> multiset = HashMultiset.create();
    for (Set<? extends E> set : sets) {
        multiset.addAll(set);
    }
    return Sets.filter(multiset.elementSet(), new Predicate<E>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(E element) {
            return multiset.count(element) == 1;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is it preferable than [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13778426/1175065)? Anyway i am going with the described code [here](http://ideone.com/OXhVUL)

Comment: Well, this code requires an extra library in your project, so you might prefer it if you are already using Guava. Otherwise stick with the straightforward approach that works with plain JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Create a multiset and iterate through it pulling out all elements with count 1.  `O(n)`.

Comment: @JanDvorak - I'm guessing you caught that the order was wrong; fixed.

Comment: @JanDvorak - it totally doesn't.  Thank you for debugging my answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<Integer>();

        set1.add(2);
        set1.add(4);
        set1.add(6);
        set1.add(8);
        set1.add(9);
        HashSet<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
        set2.add(2);
        set2.add(8);
        set2.add(9);
        HashSet<Integer> set3 = new HashSet<Integer>();
        set3.add(2);
        set3.add(4);
        set3.add(8);
        set3.add(9);
        set1.removeAll(set2);
        set1.removeAll(set3);
        System.out.println(set1);
    }
```

Comment: What about elements that occur in set2 but not set1?

Comment: look at [**this**](http://ideone.com/qTGbhX). I took 6 from set1 to set2, and above is failing...

Answer (score 0):

How about creating 2 new Hashsets. Called seenOnce and seenMoreThenOnce.

Then you iterate over all your integers in the different hashmaps.

```
For each integer:
   If it is in seenMoreThenOnce do nothing.
   else If it is in seenOnce, remove it from seenOnce and add it to seenMoreThenOnce
   Else add it to seenOnce.
```

When you are done iterating over all your hashmaps, seenOnce will contain the integers seen only once.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException {

    int count=0;
    HashSet<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer, String> ee=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("how many elements u want to store");
    int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("enter te element u want insert");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        boolean x=set1.add(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
        if(x==false)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("no of duplicate elements is   "+count);
    }
}
```